# Should I define my ElasticSearch mapping before inputing data via Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've seen that it is possible to define an ElasticSearch mapping for new data through ElasticSearch and it is also possible for logstash to create a mapping on the fly based on the data.

Which of the two is recommended?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an either-or situation. You can specify explicit mappings *and* have Elasticsearch pick suitable mappings for the fields you haven't provided an explicit mapping for. Sometimes Elasticsearch is sufficiently clever to do a fine job of choosing a mapping but other times you're smarter.

It's Elasticsearch that picks the mapping based on the field contents, not Logstash. Logstash, however, by default configures the explicit mappings for its indexes, which you can disable with the [manage_template](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch#manage_template) option to the [elasticsearch output plugin](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch).

Comment: I am using a XML filter which creates certain fields on the fly as they arrive.I wish to set their mapping by default to string for all the fields. How can this be done. I tried specifying a template as posted here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-mapping-select-all-fields-via-template-to-change-the-data-type/68177 but nothing works to select all the fields and set their data type to strings.